# User.avatarURL not showing image in MessageEmbed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have made an embed where the bot should show the author's avatar but it is not displaying the image. The user ID shows up correctly.

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
    .addField('Trivia Answer', ans)
    .setTimestamp()
    .addField('userID', message.author.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest discord.js version? If so it would be `message.author.displayAvatarURL()`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=defaultAvatarURL

Comment: defaultAvatarURL is working as for latest discord yes i am using the latest one 12.2.0. 
I tried message.author.displayAvatarURL() , It is not working

Comment: Looks like there's a lot of ways to get it, the reason your code didn't work was because it's a function, just envoke it and it should work, (tested it). Also `displayAvatarURL()` worked for me.